# Datadog Grok Pattern to extract a string

Tags: datadog

I want to extract a string from the logs, I'm pushing lambda logs using OTEL to Datadog, once the logs pushed to the Datadog I need to get the function name from Cloudwatch log group name. I've tried with the Grok parser but couldn't succeed. Here is the sample log;

```
{"cloudwatch": {
"log": {
                    "stream": "2024/02/26/[$LATEST]beef413afead461a884b58f853cc5171",
                    "group": {
                        "name": "/aws/lambda/test-function"
                    }
                }
            }}
```

Can someone provide a Grok Parser rule to extract this string into a new feild